# I am getting error while running undercover on mac `file changed before we could read it (Rugged::FilesystemError)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rugged

I am running `undercover` command and I am getting error as `file changed before we could read it (Rugged::FilesystemError)`
I am on MacOS Sonoma.
I have installed gem 'undercover' on Ruby 3.3.0

I checked that the lcov file is present.
I even copied that file to another location and used that path in the command.
Following is backtrace

```
/Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover/changeset.rb:27:in `each_patch': file changed before we could read it (Rugged::FilesystemError)
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover/changeset.rb:27:in `update'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover/cli.rb:26:in `new'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover/cli.rb:26:in `run_report'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/lib/undercover/cli.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/bin/undercover:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/3.3.0/benchmark.rb:313:in `realtime'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/undercover-0.5.0/bin/undercover:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/undercover:25:in `load'
    from /Users/dark_coder/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/undercover:25:in `<main>'
```